# Dynamics CRM Plugin Code signing

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011, code-signing, certificate-authority

My company has created an plugin for Microsoft Dynamics CRM in Visual Studio 2012, we have created a self signed certificate with Visual Studio and the plugin works. We have Certification Authority Server which can issue certificates but the problem is creating an CSR (Certification Signing Request) after much google-ing we haven't found any programs that will create the CSR, we even tryed the OpenSSL but it won't work.

The certification authority is asking for CSR, with what tool can i create a CSR so that i can give it to the CA ?

Answer (score 4):

The signing process you already did is enough, the steps are explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695782.aspx#sign

Inside Dynamics CRM a signed assembly for plugins is required to avoid name conflicts with other plugin assemblies.

Comment: Thank you, but as i said, we need to get an certificate from our company Certification Authority, the self signed certificate is already created and working....